# "If" part not executing (C#)

Tags: c#, if-statement

As a part of my programming class, I'm fairly new to it so I need some help.

I have to create a program that does the following (loosely translated) :

1. Create a program that will let a child practice his mathematics;
2. Make him type in a number, an arithmetic operator, another number and finally, the answer to the equation;
3. If the answer to said equation is correct, display a message saying "Bravo";
4. If the answer is NOT correct. make him type in another answer.  He has a maximum of 8 chances (including the first one); and
5. If after 8 tries he still doesn't get the answer to his own equation, you can tell him to go take a break.

The problem that I have in my code is that one of the last conditions ( if (ans == nb3)) never executes even.

For example, I'd type in 1 - 1 = 5. It would say that my answer is `false` and that I need to type another answer, to this point, everything is fine. If I were to type in the right answer after that ( 1 - 1 = 0 ), it would still ask me to type in another answer instead of breaking the loop.

The current state of my program:

```
        int nb1, nb2, nb3, ans = 0;
        string op;
        Console.WriteLine("Entrez un premier chiffre");
        nb1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Entrez un operateur arithmetique ");
        op = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Entrez un deuxieme chiffre");
        nb2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Quel est la reponse");
        nb3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        switch (op)
        {

            case ("+"):
            case ("plus"):
                ans = nb1 + nb2;
                break;

            case ("-"):
            case ("moins"):
                ans = nb1 - nb2;
                break;

            case ("*"):
            case ("multiplie"):
                ans = nb1 * nb2;
                break;

            case ("/"):
            case ("divise"):
                ans = nb1 / nb2;
                break;
        }

        if (ans == nb3)
            Console.WriteLine("Bravo");

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mauvaise reponse");
            for (int t = 1; t < 8; t++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Quel est la reponse?");
                Console.ReadLine();
                    if (ans == nb3)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

               }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Excuse me? Watch your language in questions please.

Comment: You don't need to tell us what you can use, these questions are intended to help everyone, not just you.

Comment: Forgot to edit that part out when writting it here. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Dr. Roflcopter The term "p*** off" is considered offensive language. I've edited it to say "go away" (pending approval).  You may find yourself using this site a lot in your career, and if some potential employer were to discover your handle here and read that, well, it's just not a good look. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll keep that in mind next time I'll post here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never re-assign your input variable in the for loop:

```
 for (int t = 1; t < 8; t++)
 {  
     Console.WriteLine("Quel est la reponse?");
     Console.ReadLine();
     if (ans == nb3)
         break;   
 }
```

Notice that you do nothing with the return value of `Console.ReadLine`. You need

```
for (int t = 1; t < 8; t++)
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Quel est la reponse?");
    nb3 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      if (ans == nb3)
         break;    
}
```

So that the new user input will be compared against `ans` instead of the previously entered value.

As a matter of style, try to avoid variable names like "nb1" "nb2" and "nb3" as they are not very descriptive. Also, if you have numbered variables like that, its almost a surefire bet that you need an *array* instead of multiple variables.

Comment: Bradly .. isn't this question way too broad?  It just states a bunch of requirements and doesn't even have an actual question.  So why answer it?

Comment: @JK. He has a problem statement: "The problem that I have in my code is that one of the last conditions ( if (ans == nb3)) never executes even" and shows his attempt. My answer shows he was just missing one critical piece. I agree its not going to win question of the year, but as far as homework questions go, it was decent.

Comment: @JK with the code that's presented it's not that broad that the difference from thinking outside the box and being able to quickly refactor the code into a working solution using a different type of loop..

Comment: Thank you for the comment but it did not solve my problem. The problem is that the console wouldn't close after you failed 2 times and get the right answer. It would keep going until "i" hits 8.

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter Right... because you never assigned the input variable in the loop. Did you try my suggestion? Note that "Bravo" won't be printed, but would be trivial to add, the program currently will just end when the correct answer was inputted

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/T9RUABs.png - I did what you said but it wouldn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter I would set a breakpoint on the if statement and see what `nb3` and `ans` are. It looks right to me though. If the values are correct, see if you break is working as expected.

Comment: And if you can't set a breakpoint, just printout ans and nb3 after each new nb3 has been parsed.

Comment: [I put it in ideone and got the expected result](http://ideone.com/Y8p7vV). (Added some print statements for clarity though.)

Comment: @31eee384 Appreciate the sanity check :)

Comment: I've rechecked the code and realised I made a VERY stupid mistake when editing it earlier. Thank you for the help Bradley, your fix worked. Hope that putting up with my very little knowlege in C# wasn't too painful for ya.

Comment: @Dr.Roflcopter Like I told JK, your question was decent for a beginner/homework one, if anything you just included a little too *much* information (far better than including too little). Your coding style will get better and more mature in time I'm sure :)